# .Net Windows application using OLEDB with Access

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ms-access

I am trying to Insert a record in MS Access DB using OLEDB in windows application.

I am getting an error "missing semicolon at end of sql statement" there is no syntax error in sql insert statment.

**My code**

This is the insert statement i am using:

```
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('SRI-10-101','001','guru','30/05/2010 12:00:00 AM','','','','','','','600028','','','','','','','30/05/2010 11:25:44 AM','');
```

along with the code:

```
conn = this.GetConnection();// which returns Connection object
tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn; 
cmd.CommandText = strQuery;// Insert statement
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Transaction = tran;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tran.Commit();
```

I tried with semicolon also still i get error;

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code. Without it, it's going to be difficult to diagnose your problem.

Comment: dude where is SQL statement or the command you are using?

Comment: Would you post the SQL-statement please and/or a code snippet?

Comment: So you maybe actually missing a semicolon at the end of the sql statement :)
Post your Code so everyone can take a look and find the error :)

Comment: The problem is that you are missing a semicolon at the end of your sql statement. Should be easy to fix :-)

Comment: Can you place SQL query and code ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the delimiters on the date values to # instead of '?

Comment: Can you post your table structure as well? Including whether you have specified NOT NULL for any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set your strQuery to the value of your insert statement.

Based on your code it should look something like this:

```
string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Student
            VALUES ('SRI-10-101','001','guru','30/05/2010 12:00:00 AM','','','','','','','600028','','','','','','','30/05/2010 11:25:44 AM','')";
```

As always you should verify that you are connected and defaulted to the proper database (or specify it explicitly prior to your table name (i.e. MyAwesomeDatabase.dbo.Student).

Finally it also looks like you are trying to insert a number as a character array ('001' or '600028'), if the fields in your database are of a numeric type then SQL prefers numbers without quote delimiters.

Good luck!